# Left join vs. inner join not returning expected records

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to find all of the most recent records (attempt_date) for a given "course" for each user. The query below returns the correct date for each user, *unless the user doesn't have an attempt_date.* In that case, the query does not return a row with the user at all.

If I change the inner joins on gradebook_grade and attempt to left join, it returns all enrolled users, but the query then returns null values if a null value exists for the any submission in the "course" rather than just the most recent attempt_date. Query here (forgive the weird naming conventions for term in the where clause, I did not choose those):

```
select distinct on (cu.pk1)
cu.pk1
,cm.course_id
,a.attempt_date
from course_users cu
    inner join course_main cm on cm.pk1 = cu.crsmain_pk1
    inner join course_term ct on ct.crsmain_pk1 = cm.pk1 /* through table */
    inner join term t on t.pk1 = ct.term_pk1
    inner join gradebook_grade gg on gg.course_users_pk1 = cu.pk1
    inner join attempt a on a.gradebook_grade_pk1 = gg.pk1
where t.name like '%Fall 2021%'
    and cu.role = 'S'
    and cu.row_status = '0'
order by cu.pk1, course_id, attempt_date desc
```

How can I sidestep this behavior? If a student *only* has null values in a course for submission dates, I want the null value. If a student has *anything other than* a null value for submission dates in a course, I want the most recent last attempt date.

*Edited to give minimal reproducible example.

Comment: Hi - please can you update your question to provide a minimal reproducible example? For example, I'm guessing the subquery for prof has no relevance to the issue your facing and the same is true for other tables. Once you've done that, please provide an explanation of the issue that makes reference to your tables: you talk about submission date but nowhere in your SQL is anything that is named similar to that. Bear in mind that the people trying to help you know nothing about your objects/data apart from the information that you provide

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! I just edited to what I think is the minimal example. Some of the issue is that a couple through tables are required to get at the data correctly. If you see something else that doesn't seem right please let me know!

Comment: Difficult to follow you. How can you get the most recent `attempt_date` for a given `course_main` with your query ? I can see on one side the JOIN between `course_user` and `course_main`, and on the other side the JOIN between `course_user` and `attempt` through the intermediate JOIN with `gradebook_grade`, but this does not link one given course with one (or several) attempt_date directly ?

Comment: The SQL is now clearer but you still haven't explained what a submission is represented by in your data. I'm guessing that submissions are stored in the attempt table and submission date = attempt_date, but I could be wrong

Comment: @NickW Yes, I'm sorry if I wasn't clearer. By submission date, I meant attempt_date.

Comment: @Edouard H: Users are associated with course_main via the course_users table, and each record has its own primary key in the course_users table. From there, each course_user can have multiple attempts for multiple gradebook_grade items, and those gradebook_grade items are 1) associated with a course_user and 2) associated with a course in course_main.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can, please write the structure of tables (create table DDL commands) and sample data. I will help you. But, I understood that: For example, we have 5 records in `course_users` table, and in the `gradebook_grade` may be have 7-8-10 records for only linked user3 and user4. Which users are not data in `gradebook_grade` table, we must select these users as null values, but which users have data in the `gradebook_grade` table, these users must be selected as one by one with the last attempt_date field.

For Example:

| course_users.pk1 | course_main.course_id | attempt_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 30 |  |
| 2 | 30 |  |
| 3 | 30 | 2021-03-10 |
| 4 | 20 | 2021-08-01 |
| 5 | 20 |  |

In this example, user3 and user4 have courses, but other users don't have.

Firstly we write a query that will select only users, which has courses and group these users by the last attaempt_date

```
select g1.course_users_pk1, max(a1.attempt_date) as attempt_date from attempt a1 
        inner join gradebook_grade g1 on a1.gradebook_grade_pk1 = g1.pk1 
        group by g1.course_users_pk1
```

Result:

| course_users_pk1 | attempt_date |
| --- | --- |
| 3 | 2021-03-10 |
| 4 | 2021-08-01 |

Then completing our full query, with left joining this query to our main tables. Our final query:

```
select distinct on (cu.pk1)
    cu.pk1, 
    cm.course_id,
    gg.attempt_date
from course_users cu
    left join course_main cm on cm.pk1 = cu.crsmain_pk1
    left join course_term ct on ct.crsmain_pk1 = cm.pk1 /* through table */
    left join term t on t.pk1 = ct.term_pk1 and t.name like '%2021%'
    left join (
        select g1.course_users_pk1, max(a1.attempt_date) as attempt_date from attempt a1 
        inner join gradebook_grade g1 on a1.gradebook_grade_pk1 = g1.pk1 
        group by g1.course_users_pk1
    ) gg on cu.pk1 = gg.course_users_pk1
where  
    cu.role = 'S' 
    and cu.row_status = '0'
order by cu.pk1, course_id, attempt_date desc
```

Maybe I misunderstood your question or your table structure, I am sorry, but if you can write create tables and some samples data I'm trying to help you.

Comment: This was exactly what I needed! Thank you. I had worked this out slightly differently, but the end result was roughly the same. I needed to left join on the aggregated subquery. Also, thanks for the heads up on giving table structure data. I will do that next time.